# Como mostrar mas de un valor en una lista en python por medio del array de las variables

Tags: python, array, lista

Principalmente hay un problema que tengo, la verdad mi codigo funciona bien pero quisiera saber como puedo mostrar 2 valores de una lista con solo una variable ya que seria mucho mas facil así. Aquí esta el codigo:

```
datos = ("Juan", "Perez", 53.44)
format_string = "Hola "

print("%s%s %s. Tu balance es de %g$"%(format_string, datos[0], datos[1], datos[2]))
```

Entonces quisiera saber en `Datos[0]` como puedo hacer para que se muestre `Datos[1]` ahí mismo sin tener que agregar otra variable. Es decir mas o menos `Datos[0, 1]` pero esto me da un error. Algo mas o menos así. Saludos

Ah y otra cosa que tambien el codigo funcione con %s y %d asi que por favor si van a modificar el codigo que funcione con esos formatos.

Comment: Usa el operador *unpacking* `*` de esta forma `print("%s%s %s. Tu balance es de %g$"%(format_string, *datos))`

Comment: Ah excelente respuesta christian me ha servido de mucho

Answer (score 0):

Hola buenas la respuesta de Christian está muy bien, también podrías crear una función que te concatene esos dos índices. Te pongo tu forma la de Christian y la función.bun saludo. Por cierto está declarada una tupla no una lista no sé si nombras que querías lista y o una tupla

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-



datos = ("Juan", "Perez", 53.44)
format_string = "Hola "
```

Tu solución

```
print("%s%s %s. Tu balance es de %g$"%(format_string, datos[0], datos[1], datos[2]))
```

Solución de Christian

```
print("%s%s %s. Tu balance es de %g$"%(format_string, *datos))
```

Con función:

```
def union_indices(lista):
  union=lista[0]+' '+lista[1]
  return union

print("%s %s. Tu balance es de %g$"%(format_string, 
union_indices(datos), datos[2]))
```

Comment: Para hacer un poco más general tu función podrías usar el método `join` pero claro, antes deberías transformar los números en string, solo por curiosidad la dejo por aquí `return " ".join(f"{n}" for n in lista)`